# Прерывание цикла Python

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-нибудь вставить в тело цикла  после `keyboard.wait('ctrl')` команду, которая при нажатии на 'esc' прервет цикл и перейдет к дальнейшему выполнению программы? `pg` - это pyautogui.

```
def click(y):
    for i in range(40):
        pg.doubleClick(95, y)
        pg.click(37, y)
        keyboard.wait('ctrl')
        pg.click(681, 80)
        pg.click(681, 127)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        y += 16
click(135)
#остальная программа
```

Comment: Можно. Вставьте проверку на `esc` и прерывание цикла. Как еще-то?

Comment: И у вас явно что-то не то с отступами.

Comment: Извините за назойливость, может тут так не принято, я только пятый день этим занимаюсь. Но как вставить эту проверку? Или может где можно почитать про это.

Comment: Советую почитать какой-нибудь хороший подробный учебник по питону, навроде Лутца. После его прочтения у вас гораздо лучше отложатся в голове основные механики питона. Проверка — это оператор `if`. Прерывается цикл с помощью `break`.

Comment: И отложите `pyautogui` до лучших времен, запутаетесь. Если вам так хочется изучить какую-нибудь библиотеку, учите модули `re`, `functools`, `itertools`. Они не слишком сложны и при изучении самых азов можно пробовать к ним подступаться. Не встроенные до времени лучше не трогать.

Answer (score 0):

Вставить цикл отслеживания эвента нажатия на esc как while:

```
def click(y):
    for i in range(40):
        pg.doubleClick(95, y)
        pg.click(37, y)
        keyboard.wait('ctrl')
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
                return
            time.sleep(0.1)

        pg.click(681, 80)
        pg.click(681, 127)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        y += 16

click(135)
```